# Is this set non-existent or simply excluding two points?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers

The set is simply defined as: $|z-a|=|z-b|$ where $z,a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ and $a\neq b$.

Now for $z=a$, we have: $|a-a|=0=|a-b| \rightarrow a=b$. This contradicts our hypothesis. The same happens for $z=b$. Now my first thought was that this meant that this set does not exist because I thought $a$ and $b$ would obviously belong to the set. However now I'm realizing the alternative seems much more plausible: that this set is $\mathbb{C}-[a,b]$. In other words, a disk with two punctures.

Comment: This is the set of points that are equidistant from $a$ and $b$. it is not a disk nor a punctured plane.

Comment: Usually when it's typographically like this we are looking at the set $S_{a,b}=\{z\in\Bbb C\,:\, \lvert z-a\rvert=\lvert z-b\rvert\}$. Therefore your assertion for $z=a$ only proves that $a\notin S_{a,b}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio It's more clear when the set is fully written out like that,from now on I'll do it whenever confusion arises.

Comment: And $0\notin[1,2]$, so $[1,2]$ doesn't exist???????????

Comment: As an aside, when you say, "This contradicts our hypothesis," it only contradicts the hypothesis that $z = a$. It doesn't contradict the hypothesis that the set exists. ¶ I find that such problems are easier to think about, perhaps, if you pick some example values for $a$ and $b$. Suppose $a = -1$ and $b = 1$; what $z$ would satisfy the equation. Surely $0$, but are there any others? Don't forget you're looking across all of $\mathbb{C}$. What about if $a = 1$ and $b = i$? And so on.

Comment: " I thought a and b would obviously belong to the set."  Why would you think that?

Comment: " I thought a and b would obviously belong to the set."  Actually that doesn't make sense.  $a$ and $b$ are variables used to define the set and not any well defined values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it might be easier to think of this visually.

Consider the shape $|z-a| = r$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C},r \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. This would be a circle of radius $r$ and center $a$.

Put differently: $|z-a|$ gives the distance between $z$ and $a$.

---

Let

$$S :=  \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z-a|=|z-b| \}$$

Suppose $z \in S$; what does this mean? It thus means that $z$ is equally distant from $a$ and $b$.

The obvious candidate point would be their midpoint, $(a+b)/2$. (This is easy to verify.) Of course, $a,b$ can't be in $S$, being distinct. But also clearly it wouldn't be a twice-punctured disc.

In fact, if you think for a moment back to geometry and constructions, this all should immediately suggest an idea:

**Let $\ell$ be the line segment connecting $a,b$. Then $S$ is the line perpendicular to $\ell$, through $(a+b)/2$.**

I'll leave the justification to you.

Comment: So the set is the line that goes through the midpoint and is perpendicular to the line connecting $a$ and $b$, right?

Comment: Yes. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$